# Sigar API for JAVA (need a guide)

Tags: java, windows, sigar

I've downloaded Sigar API ( http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home ) and would like to use it in a project to get information about different processes which are running.

My problem is that I can't really find some useful code snippets to learn from and the javadoc from their website isn't of much help, because I don't know what I should be looking for.

Do you have any ideea where I could find more information?

Comment: I used SIGAR before, and found it quite easy.  Can you specify exactly what you're looking for?  The PTQL doc page combines with the javadoc seems a pretty good start to me.

Comment: So, as a starting point, I need the information about proccessor/memory usage for a certain process, like explorer.exe (example).

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, so I won't post this as a reply; I think you just do ProcMem pm = new ProcMem(); pm.gather(sigar, yourPid); pm.getsize().  Analog for cpu with ProcTime.  You can use ProcessFinder to find a pid from a PTQL expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To find the `pid` (which is needed to find out information about a certain process), you can use a `ProcessFinder`.
The method to find a single process pid is `findSingleProcess(String expression)`. Example:

```
    Sigar sigar=new Sigar();
    ProcessFinder find=new ProcessFinder(sigar);
    long pid=find.findSingleProcess("Exe.Name.ct=explorer");
    ProcMem memory=new ProcMem();
    memory.gather(sigar, pid);
    System.out.println(Long.toString(memory.getSize()));
```

The expression syntax is this:

```
Class.Attribute.operator=value
```

Where:

```
Class is the name of the Sigar class minus the Proc prefix.
Attribute is an attribute of the given Class, index into an array or key in a Map class.
operator is one of the following for String values:
eq - Equal to value
ne - Not Equal to value
ew - Ends with value
sw - Starts with value
ct - Contains value (substring)
re - Regular expression value matches
operator is one of the following for numeric values:
eq - Equal to value
ne - Not Equal to value
gt - Greater than value
ge - Greater than or equal value
lt - Less than value
le - Less than or equal value
```

More info here through the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20170201073935/http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/PTQL

Comment: I am trying to use `findSingleProcess("Exe.Name.ct=explorer");` as you say and I'm getting this error `org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: Query did not match any processes`. And the `explorer.exe` process is running as I can see in the Task manager.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: The documentation site can only be accessed though wayback machine now: https://web.archive.org/web/20170201073935/http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/PTQL

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 7 try doing something

```
likefindSingleProcess("State.Name.ct=explorer");
```

Answer (score 0):

In their latest package, they give a lot of usage examples under `bindings\java\examples`. Check them out.

Answer (score 0):

The hyperic site seems to be gone, but this https://layer4.fr/blog/2016/10/10/os-monitoring-with-java/ tells you how to hook Sigar to Java. You do need to put the sigar-amd64-winnt.dll file somewhere on the DLL path (e.g. C:\Windows)